# jQuery equivalents to ExtJS functions extend(), apply() and namespace()?

Tags: jquery, extjs, helper, equivalent

ExtJS provides some great helper functions like:

- Ext.extend()
- Ext.apply()
- Ext.namespace()

**Are there any equivalents in jQuery?** I know I could port all three to jQuery since I like them so much, but maybe I'm missing something that's already there. I would like to avoid mingling with prototypes myself if possible.

**Endresult**

- Ext.apply(obj1, obj2) => $.extend(obj1, obj2)
- Ext.extend(obj1, obj2) => $.extend(obj1.prototype, obj2)
- Ext.ns(string) => custom implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `extend` function is like ExtJS's `apply` function in that it copies data members from the source to the destination. The others *might* be already made as plugins, but I don't know of any.

Comment: doesn't jQuery's extend() function only extend "element set" type and is not intended for extending any other object instances?

Comment: great. I guess Ext.extend() can be used with the same jquery function just specifying type prototype instead of an instance. What about namespace?

Comment: I think `extend` is the only one that jQuery supports out of the box. There might be plugins available for the other two, but I don't know of them. But as you said, you are willing to make them yourself and they aren't difficult.